# Search all attributes in the entire DOM for text

Tags: jquery

I need to search the entire DOM for text but want to limit the search only to properties (attributes). I am only aware of searching for properties if you already know their names. Example:

```
$(document).find("[name='description']");
```

But I want something like:

```
$(document).find("[*='description']");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the prettiest of solutions since it requires you to loop through all elements on the page, but you could check the `attributes` property of all elements.

```js
$(function() {
  $("*").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
      if (this.value=='description') {
        console.log('Found for attribute "'+this.name+'".');
        console.log('Text: '+$el.text());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-test1="description">test1</div>
<div data-test2="bla" id="description">test2</div>
<div data-test3="bla bla" class="description">test3</div>
<div data-test4="description" class="description">test4</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a bit of magic, I don't know if it's possible.

But here is one way to do it with a little extension.

```js
$.expr[":"].FindAttrByValue = function(element, index, ElVal){
    var g = $(element.attributes).filter(function () {
        return this.value === ElVal[3];
    }).length;
    if (g > 0) {
        return element;
    }
};
var e =$(document).find('*:FindAttrByValue("description")');
console.log(e.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div custom="description">test</div>
```